# SED in bash for receiving parameters

Tags: bash, sed

This is my script, in which I want to receive arguments --path and --mode by user, for example:

*./myscript.sh --path=/hello --mode=a*

**script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

HELP=false
MODE=false
PATH=false

for arg in "$@"
do
    case "$arg" in
        -h|--help) 
            HELP=true
            ;;      
        --mode*)
            MODE=`echo $arg | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//g'`
            ;;
        --path*)
            PATH=`echo $arg | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//g'`
            ;;      
        *)
            echo "wrong argument: $arg"
            echo "type --help for supported parameters"
            exit 1
        ;;

    esac
done
```

When I try to execute, I receive this error:

```
line 19: sed: command not found
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: the obvious question: do you have sed installed?

Comment: What is the $PATH of the user executing this script? Can sed be found in that PATH?

Comment: I'm using git bash under windows, if I try to execute only "sed" it works (It's GNU version)

Comment: Why would you use `sed` for this at all? See [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) for discussion of best practices around command-line argument parsing, which showcases parameter expansion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PATH=false
```

This line destroys your `PATH` variable. `PATH` is where the shell looks up all commands you want to run. (External commands, that is; built-in shell commands, functions, and aliases are not affected.)

Normally it contains things like `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`. By setting it to `false` you're telling bash to search the (non-existent) directory `false` for commands.

This is why `sed` (which is an external command) cannot be found.

In general you should avoid ALL_UPPERCASE names for your own script variables because many of those ALL_UPPERCASE variables are reserved / already used by the shell or the system in general.

---

You said you're running this on Windows. I believe environment variables are case-insensitive on Windows, so even using `path` instead may not help here. You may have to choose a different name for your variable, such as `my_path`.

Comment: Completely overlooked that. Nice catch.

Comment: @melpomene Bullseye.

Answer (score 3):

The nice answer @melpomene gave fixes your immediate `sed` problem, and it also mentions one good habit in shell programming -- avoiding uppercase names for non-environment variables (you might find Google's [Shell Style Guide, variable names section](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml#Variable_Names) helpful).

But besides that, your `sed` line is completely unnecessary. You can replace the expensive command substitution and call to the external `sed`:

```
MODE=`echo $arg | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//g'
```

with [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), prefix pattern strip:

```
mode="${arg#*=}"
```

Also, when using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution), better use the `$(command)` form instead of backticks (also mentioned in the [style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml#Command_Substitution) cited above). It'll be easier to read, and to nest other calls to command substitutions (all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially).

When iterating over arguments, you might find the `while (($# > 0))` loop more convenient (coupled with `shift N`), if you need to handle parameters with varying number of arguments, e.g. `-m val`, `-mval` and `--mode=val`. But in that case you would be better off with [`getopts`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-getopts) (few examples [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)) anyway.